# store image in id3v2 frame apic

Tags: linux, command-line, id3v2, apic

I want to find some command line utility (Linux), that can store images in ID3v2 APIC frame
but cant find anything,

Tried using ID3v2 util but id doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I found only eyeD3
and it works fine